# How can I find Index of Dictionary within NSArray which has matching key value - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
(
        {
        "date" = "23-02-2016";
        filename = "65.pdf";
    },
        {
        "date" = "23-02-2016";
        filename = "78.pdf";
    },
        {
        "date" = "23-02-2016";
        filename = "abc.pdf";
    }
)
```

I have an array Like this. I want to find **Index** of dictionary which has filename = "abc.pdf". How can I find? my array is NSArray and dictionary is NSMutableDictionary.
It will be great help if anyone can guide me.

Thanks..

Comment: Ok.. Thanks!! It works for me..

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileterArray: NSArray = yourArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "self.%@ contains[c] %@", "filename", "abc.pdf"))

for (NSInteger i=0;i<fileterArray.count:i++){
     NSInteger anIndex=[yourArray indexOfObject:[fileterArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     NSLog(@"%d",anIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the sample NSMutableDictionary and NSArray. Use the predicate to collect the "abc.pdf" filename in to filterArray and loop it to get the index.

```
    let dic1 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "23-02-2011", forKey: "date");
    dic1.setValue("65.pdf", forKey: "filename");
    let dic2 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "23-02-2012", forKey: "date");
    dic2.setValue("65.pdf", forKey: "filename");
    let dic3 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "23-02-2013", forKey: "date");
    dic3.setValue("abc.pdf", forKey: "filename");
    let dic4 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "23-02-2014", forKey: "date");
    dic4.setValue("abc1.pdf", forKey: "filename");
    let dic5 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "23-02-2015", forKey: "date");
    dic5.setValue("abc.pdf", forKey: "filename");


    let testArray :NSArray = NSArray.init(array: [dic1,dic2,dic3,dic4,dic5]);
    let filterArray: NSArray = testArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "self.%@ contains[c] %@", "filename", "abc.pdf"));

    for(var i = 0; i < filterArray.count; i++) {
        let anIndex: NSInteger = testArray.indexOfObject(filterArray[i]);
        NSLog("%d",anIndex);
    }
```

It will give you filter array values if the dictionary values repeated you will get all values index here.

Comment: In above-voted answer, you will get the only one index with - indexOfObjectPassingTest and it won't find the repeated values in your dictionaries array.

Comment: My dictionary has no repeated values. That's why I have voted.

Comment: Oh got it now... Pls update question correctly.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: @VigneshKumar: If the user want all the indexes (and not only the first one), he can use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet.

```
  let fileArray = yourArray.valueForKey("filename")        
  let indexofDict = fileArray.indexOfObject("abc.pdf")
  print(indexofDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
  NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
  NSString *s = (NSString*)obj;
  NSRange range = [s rangeOfString: searchString];
 return range.location != NSNotFound;
}];
```